# Poison.EncodeError unable to encode value: {"has already been taken", []}

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison

I am trying to return an invalid changeset.

When doing

```
conn
|> put_status(422)
|> put_view(Elemental.Auth.ErrorView)
|> render("422.json-api", %{data: changeset})
```

OR

```
conn
|> put_status(422)
|> put_view(Elemental.Auth.ErrorView)
|> render(:errors, data: changeset)
```

using JaSerializer
I am getting

```
(Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {"has already been taken", []}
```

This was unexpected. It was working earlier.
I have  `{:poison, "~> 2.0"},`

**UPDATE**

```
>> d
%{errors: [shortcode: {"has invalid format", [validation: :format]}]}
iex(11)> Map.replace(d, :errors, [shortcode: Tuple.to_list(shortcode)]) |> Poison.encode
{:error,
 {:invalid, {:shortcode, ["has invalid format", [validation: :format]]}}}
```

Comment: It cannot encode a tuple which is apparently a part of your changeset data, you gotta change it to something which can be encoded.

Comment: @JustMichael see update

Answer (score 1):

Poison never knew how to [encode](https://github.com/devinus/poison/blob/master/lib/poison/encoder.ex) the tuple. You can easily convert tuple to the list:

```
a = {"has already been taken", []}

a 
|> Tuple.to_list() # ["has already been taken", []]
|> Poison.encode!() # "[\"has already been taken\",[]]"
```

Or simply get first_entry from the tuple using pattern matching:

```
{message, _list} = {"has already been taken", []}
```

**Edit**:

Your code is crashing when trying to display explicitly the `changeset`. The best solution to avoid that is to create specific view, that will return JSON where you can prepare how you want to display the errors eg.

```
def render("422.json-api", %{data: data}) do
  # data is actually changeset, which you are passing here
  errors = Enum.map(data.errors, fn {field, message} -> 
    %{field: "#{field} has error: #{message}"
  end)

  %{errors: errors}
end
```

Comment: see updates, what do you mean >but it turns out you displaying propably only the first one ?

Comment: Ok I edited my answer. The easiest way to avoid explicitly using `Poison.encode!` is to create View that will do that implicitly for you and you have full control what you want to render.

Comment: because it was a tuple, i just extracted and matched the clause and yielded the output. thanks